# How to change the Content of a <textarea> with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How would I change the content of a `<textarea>` element with JavaScript?

I want to make it empty.

Comment: For php you would: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318132/setting-value-of-a-html-form-textarea/3318143

Answer (score 351, accepted):

Like this:

```
document.getElementById('myTextarea').value = '';
```

or like this in jQuery:

```
$('#myTextarea').val('');
```

Where you have

```
<textarea id="myTextarea" name="something">This text gets removed</textarea>
```

For all the downvoters and non-believers:

- [Here's the MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535122(VS.85).aspx)

  > value Property: Retrieves or sets the text in the entry field of the textArea element.
- [Here's the MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLTextAreaElement)

  > value   DOMString   The raw value contained in the control.

Comment: Didn't think value would work cause there is no. value= in it but thanks!

Comment: does not work in internet explorer on windows mobile devices.

Comment: doesn't work with chrome v61, the value doesn't effect that's in the input box

Comment: That's kinda weird, but sadly it seems true. Do you know why @AeroWang? / edit: typo

Comment: I used the `.value` attribute in Chrome v119 (2023) to set textarea content and it works fine. Seems a bug has been fixed.

Comment: It seems like this ("used the `.value` attribute in Chrome") is true after the HTMLInputElement is added to the DOM, but it only clears the property if the element has been cloned and not yet added to the DOM; `innerText = ''` solves that. Verified in Chrome v120 (2024)

Answer (score 23):

**If** you can use jQuery, and I highly recommend you do, you would simply do

```
$('#myTextArea').val('');
```

Otherwise, it is browser dependent. Assuming you have

```
var myTextArea = document.getElementById('myTextArea');
```

In most browsers you do

```
myTextArea.innerHTML = '';
```

But in Firefox, you do

```
myTextArea.innerText = '';
```

Figuring out what browser the user is using is left as an exercise for the reader. Unless you use jQuery, of course ;)

**Edit**: I take that back. Looks like support for .innerHTML on textarea's has improved. I tested in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer, all of them cleared the textarea correctly.

**Edit 2**: And I just checked, if you use .val('') in jQuery, it just sets the .value property for textarea's. So .value should be fine.

Comment: .value = ''; works in Chrome FF and Safari...   .innerHTML does not work in Chrome did not test in others.

Comment: You should not use innerHTML and innerText for textareas. The value attribute should be used. So, $('#myTextArea').val('') or document.getElementById('myTextArea').value = '' is the best option

Answer (score 10):

Although many correct answers have already been given, the classical (read non-DOM) approach would be like this:

```
document.forms['yourform']['yourtextarea'].value = 'yourvalue';
```

where in the HTML your textarea is nested somewhere in a form like this:

```
<form name="yourform">
    <textarea name="yourtextarea" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
</form>
```

And as it happens, that would work with [Netscape Navigator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Navigator) 4 and Internet Explorer 3 too. And, not unimportant, Internet Explorer on mobile devices.

Comment: Internet explorer on mobile devices? 

Answer (score 8):

If it's jQuery...

```
$("#myText").val('');
```

or

```
document.getElementById('myText').value = '';
```

Reference: *[Text Area Object](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/javascript/dom/textarea-events.php)*

Answer (score 2):

Put the textarea to a form, naming them, and just use the DOM objects easily, like this:

```
<body onload="form1.box.value = 'Welcome!'">
  <form name="form1">
    <textarea name="box"></textarea>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple vanilla JS example that changes the textarea content on a button click.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#button");
const messageBox = document.querySelector("#message");
button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
messageBox.innerText = "Please type your message here."
});
```

```html
 <h1>TextArea Examplw with JavaScript</h1>
    <textarea id="message"></textarea>
    <button id="button">Click to Change</button>
```

Comment: As of today, `<textarea>` does not support the `value` attribute. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: @AlPo Thanks. I have updated the answer by using `innerText` which does the same thing.

Comment: `innerText` removes all of the node's children and replaces them with a single text node with the given string value. In this particular case an empty string is a perfect answer to the question. However, it is worth mentioning that `HTMLTextAreaElement` interface does have a `value` attribute.