# Setting value of a HTML form textarea?

Tags: php, html

I'm using the following to set the value of a text area..

```
<?php
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
?>
<br/><b>Description</b><br/>
<TEXTAREA NAME="message" COLS=40 ROWS=6 value="<?=$message;?>"></TEXTAREA><br/><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
```

but it doesn’t appear to be working. The value of message is not null. Does anyone have any idea why it's not filling the value?

Comment: Be careful when using the `$_REQUEST` variable, if you're planning on using that data for anything more than just putting it back into a form. Based on your `variables_order` directive (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order), a user could potentially overwrite the `message` variable without you knowing. -- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: @Jeff as much as this is correct, the immediate problem is the OP not sanitizing the content of the message at all.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Textarea has no value. You need to insert your message between the opening and closing tags.

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlspecialchars($message); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: I would suggest escaping the value as well - `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Another very robust alternative for sanitizing the input is to use HTMLPurifier.

Comment: And +1 for not using shorttags, you don't always have control over your hosts php.ini and you may find that your host has disabled them, but if you use full php tags you'll never have that problem.

Comment: Also important that the PHP tags should follow right after/before the textarea even if it messes up the formatting a bit. Otherwise you get whitespace in the textarea.

Answer (score 12):

```
<textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6"><?=$message?></textarea>
```

**Note:** Make sure `$message` is properly sanitized and that `short_open_tag` is enabled. Otherwise, @fabric's accepted answer is a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this method...

```
 `<textarea  rows="12" id="mytextarea"><?php echo $bio; ?> </textarea>

  <script>
  document.getElementById(`mytextarea`).innerHTML="Include the text you want to display";
  </script>`
```