# textarea that contains pre code security

Tags: php, security, textarea

What is the most secure way to save data from a textarea that contains a `<pre><code>` text in it? , using `strip_tags` will remove all the tags from the text..

is it save to use this:

```
strip_tags($input, '<pre><code><other accepted tags except script,php,...');
```

or should I do other things too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - HTML Form TEXTAREA containing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777297/php-html-form-textarea-containing-html)

Answer (score 2):

> What is the most secure way to save data from a textarea that contains a `<pre><code>` text in it?

Save it as it is.

When you take that data back out of the database and put it into a web page, call [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on it first to escape it so that it looks like normal text on the page.

If you *want* the user to be able to input actual markup, but you only want to allow certain tags, then you've got a different problem and you want something like [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Either way, the input or database layer is not the right place to be worrying about output formatting concerns.

Answer (score 1):

If you are saving the contents of the text area to mysql database you should use mysqli_escape_string. before saving the data.

Also you can remove javascript tags from the posted data using regular expression. e.g preg_replace