# Textarea input field will not print data from db

Tags: php, html

I am simply trying to print/echo out data inputted into a database out into textfields. I have a form made up of 4 input field, one of the 4 is a textarea. I am using the following code the print the data out:

```
 <textarea id="desc" name="desc" placeholder="Item description" rows="3" maxlength="200"  
 value="<?Php print "".  $_SESSION['Product_Desc']; ?>" required ></textarea><br>
```

And it just will not print, however the moment i change the textarea into :

```
  <input id="desc" name="desc" placeholder="Item description" rows="3" maxlength="200"
  value="<?Php print "".  $_SESSION['Product_Desc']; ?>" required ><br>
```

It works perfectly. My other input fields are printing out perfectly also. So my question is there a issue with printing out data from a DB within a textarea.

Comment: Don't input it as a value, try putting it between the `textarea` tags

Comment: `textarea` has no 'value', take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318132/setting-value-of-a-html-form-textarea

Comment: @Fizz i have learnt something new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for text area print like this

```
<textarea id="desc" name="desc" placeholder="Item description" rows="3" maxlength="200"  
  required ><?Php print "".  $_SESSION['Product_Desc']; ?></textarea><br>
```