# Iframe content to store in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to retrieve the content from iframe and store it in textarea using pure JavaScript??
I have retireve the content from iframe using following code:

```
function getIframeContent(){
 var frameObj = document.getElementById(frameId);
 var frameContent = frameObj.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
 alert("frame content : "+frameContent);
 }
```

Now how to store it in the textarea??

Comment: Take a look at: [How to change the Content of a <textarea> with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642447/how-to-change-the-content-of-a-textarea-with-javascript)

Comment: but can it store styled text content in textarea that i have taken from iframe??

Answer (score 0):

You can display the content of your iFrame inside your `TextArea` like so

```
 document.getElementById('YourTextArea').innerHTML = frameContent;
```

or using the `Value` attribute:

```
document.getElementById('YourTextArea').value = frameContent;
```

I have done a [**quick demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5enxhh7/2/) for you using the first method.

This returns a string with any html tag in it. So for example if your iframe contains a list, the method returns an html list.

Here's the code:

```
<body>
    <div id="frameId">
      <ul>
        <li id="item1">Coffee</li>
        <li id="item2">Tea</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <p>Click the button get the HTML content of the iframe.</p>

    <textarea id="demo"></textarea><br/>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var frameContent = document.getElementById("frameId").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = frameContent;
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it the tone of my answer or its format you're complaining about?If it's the former, I'm not critising anyone; if it's the latter, I've seen a lot of answer like this all over SO.

Comment: Looks more like a suggestion indeed. And you are right, SO needs a little bit more cleaning, despite tremendous efforts provided by the community.

Comment: The use of "Why not trying" suggests it is not an answer, but a request for clarification.

Comment: but can it store styled text content in textarea that i have taken from iframe??

Comment: @Dura thnx for your answer but i am not getting what i desire. as from your example when we clicked the try it button we get answer like :
      <ul>
        <li id="item1">Coffee</li>
        <li id="item2">Tea</li>
      </ul>                                                            but i was trying to get the styled text in textarea  that we have in iframe  but we are getting html structure of text so i was trying to find that solution . anyway thanks for your concern!!

Comment: @Dura Some one was flagged your answer as "its not an answer". I just reviewed your answer before your updates. Yes I agree there are many answers like this. But the **flagged** Q/A will be reviewed and appropriate comment will be added by `stackoverflow` based on our reviews.