# Dynamically add variables to html table

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a table here with html.

```
<tr id='addr0'>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id='word0' placeholder='Word' 
               value="Abhor" class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id='definition0' placeholder='Definition' 
               value="regard with disgust and hatred." class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id='synonym0' placeholder='Synonyms' 
               value="detest, hate" class="form-control" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id='addr1'></tr>
```

How can I use java script to add an array or variables in the text areas. I looked around and none of the code I found worked.

this is what i've tried:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("synonym0").innerHTML = "Test";
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please provide bit of code you are working ?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so we can help.

Comment: I created a table with this as a row.   
<td>
 <input type="text" id='synonym0' placeholder='Synonyms' class="form-control"/>
 </td>I want to use javascript to add elements in there I tried document.getElementByID but nothing was showing.

Comment: This is the script I used.                                                                       <script>
    document.getElementById("synonym0" ).innerHTML = "Test";
    </script>

Answer (score 1):

input elements' content is accessed by their `value` attribute, not `innerHtml`. try:

```
document.getElementById("synonym0").value = "Test";
```

Comment: I saw that on the site but for some reason it didn't work the way I used it. Now it works, Thank you very much I'm just starting out on web development.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is answered here: [How to change the Content of a <textarea> with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642447/how-to-change-the-content-of-a-textarea-with-javascript)

but here is an [snippet](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqwZoN) anyway:

```js
// to set the content to a variable (an string):

document.getElementById('word0').value = 'Testing!';

var arr = ['member 1', 'member 2', 'member 3'];

// To set the content to an array:

document.getElementById('definition0').value = arr.toString();
```

```html
<tr id='addr0'>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id='word0' placeholder='Word' value="Value" class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id='definition0' placeholder='Definition' value="Default value" class="form-control" />
    </td>

</tr>
<tr id='addr1'></tr>
```