# Javascript DOM manipulation: changing text of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I tried to print the results of the function calculation() to the text area but it seems not working. Can you please help!

```
<head>
  <title>Lab 6</title>
<script>
function calculate(){
for (var i=100; i<1000; i++) {
var x = i%10;
var y = Math.floor((i/10)%10);
var z = Math.floor((i/100)%10);
 if (i== x*x*x +y*y*y + z*z*z) {

document.getElementbyTagname("textarea").innerHtml = i;
document.getElementbyTagname("button").addEventListener("click",
calculate());
}}} 

</script>
</head>

<body>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"> </textarea>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The function is `getElementsByTagName` not `getElementbyTagname`.  `The Element.getElementsByTagName() method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name..` [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and not work because yo cant set an event listener to HTMLCollection, you can acces to the first element like an array..

Comment: First of all, you are calling elements before being created in the DOM; second, the function document.getElementbyTagname and the property innetHtml doesn't exist; third, you cant change the value of a text area with innerHTML (what I think you are trying to do).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the Content of a <textarea> with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642447/how-to-change-the-content-of-a-textarea-with-javascript)

Comment: And fourth, you are not running the event listener of the button, so the function calculate will never executed. Please clearify your code before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to rewrite your code. try once may this help...

```
<head>
  <title>Lab 6</title>
<script>
function calculate()
{
    for (var i=100; i<1000; i++) 
    {
        var x = i%10;
        var y = Math.floor((i/10)%10);
        var z = Math.floor((i/100)%10);
        if (i== x*x*x +y*y*y + z*z*z) 
        {

            document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].innerHtml = i;

        }
    }
} 
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click",calculate());
</script>
</head>

<body>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"> </textarea>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have edit your code to make it work, I don't really get your logic, so not sure if that is what you want. But you can look at the my syntax to refine your own code. Also You made several mistakes.
1. 'getElementbyTagname' should be 'getElementsByTagName'
2. you didn't put the event function to the right place to trigger the click event.

`var btn = document.querySelector(' .btn')
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        calculate()

```
})
function calculate(){
      for (var i=100; i<1000; i++) {
                var x = i%10;
                var y = Math.floor((i/10)%10);
                var z = Math.floor((i/100)%10);
                if (i== x*x*x +y*y*y + z*z*z) {
                    var text = document.querySelector(' .demo')
                   text.innerHTML = i

                }}}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Made many changes to your code,

```js
function calculate(){
var txt="";
for (var i=100; i<1000; i++) {
var x = i%10;
var y = Math.floor((i/10)%10);
var z = Math.floor((i/100)%10);
if (i== x*x*x +y*y*y + z*z*z) 
{ 
 txt = txt + i + "\n";
 
}
}

document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Lab 6</title>
</head>

<body>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textarea"> </textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="calculate();">Click Me!</button>
</body>

</html>
```