# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two components for editing JSON objects. And i have a button that switches between these two. Here is the html code:

```
<v-btn @click="switchConfigClicked">Switch config</v-btn>
<h4 class="switchButtonInfo">Switch between editor/plain-text</h4>
<v-btn class="switchEditButton" @click="switchEditButtonClicked">Switch Editor</v-btn>
<div class= "editorComponents">
  <div v-if="showEditComponents" class="editor">
    <div v-if="showJsonEditor">
      <JsonEditor is-edit="true" v-model="editedConfig" ></JsonEditor>
    </div>
    <div v-if="showTextEditor">
      <textarea id="myTextArea" cols=75 rows=100></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
```

//Javascript code

```
switchEditButtonClicked: function(){

  this.showTextEditor = !this.showTextEditor;
  this.showJsonEditor = !this.showJsonEditor;

  if (this.showTextEditor) {

    this.editedConfig = JSON.stringify({"hello":"test"}, undefined, 4);

    document.getElementById('myTextArea').innerHTML = this.editedConfig;

  }
  else{
    //this.editedConfig = JSON.parse(this.edite)
  }

},
```

Start value for `showJsonEditor = true`, `showTextEditor = false` gives me the error:

> Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", Vue

i tried setting the the code like below

```
window.onload = function() {
    // all of your code goes in here
    // it runs after the DOM is built
}
```

No error is shown but also no text is shown.

**Test case**

i commented out these two lines from `switchConfigClicked`:

```
//this.showTextEditor = !this.showTextEditor;
//this.showJsonEditor = !this.showJsonEditor;
```

and reversed the boolean start values for `showJsonEditor = false`, `showTextEditor = true`

**Result**

Text is shown in the textEditor with no errors..

**Conclusion**

I have a feeling that it has to do with my `v-if`, when showTextEditor is set to false and then changed to true maybe we are trying to put the text in before the new DOM is created? Not really sure why and how to fix this..

Comment: This means that `document.getElementById('myTextArea')` does not find an element with the ID `myTextArea` in the DOM at the time it is called. Maybe Vue has not entered the update circle. But using `document.getElementById('myTextArea').innerHTML = ...`  in Vue is something you should not do anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `textarea` is not yet available/rendered at this point (deferred by `v-if`), try querying for it inside [`Vue.nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick).

> Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. Use it immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM update.

```
switchEditButtonClicked: function () {
  this.showTextEditor = !this.showTextEditor;
  this.showJsonEditor = !this.showJsonEditor;

  if (this.showTextEditor) {
    this.editedConfig = JSON.stringify({
        "hello": "test"
      }, undefined, 4);

    Vue.nextTick(() => {
      // Or better yet use a `ref`
      document.getElementById('myTextArea').innerHTML = this.editedConfig;
    });

  } else {
    //this.editedConfig = JSON.parse(this.edite)
  }

}
```

Comment: Just a quick question. I am using the promise version of nextTick so i am refering to the same vue instance when using `this` however i am getting: `uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property` when trying to do a console.log on my `this` variable

Comment: @TimoCengiz If you're using it with [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you shouldn't get that type error. Can  you post in here how you are using it real quick? Or maybe edit your post.

Comment: No problem, glad you sorted it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", Vue

This means that the line `document.getElementById('myTextArea').innerHTML` fails and the problem is with the lookup - `document.getElementById('myTextArea')` returns nothing, which clarifies the error message - the lookup by ID results in `null`, and you try to set the `innerHTML` of that.

You *do* have an element with `myTextArea` ID, so the reason for that is [that the element is not present when the JavaScript code runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

This also explains why setting the code to run with `window.onload` doesn't show the error - this will set it to execute after the page has been fully rendered, so the DOM element will exist and you'd be able to fetch it.

The reason why you get no text then is because you are adding it the wrong way. Instead of `.innerHTML` [you should set the `.value` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642447/how-to-change-the-content-of-a-textarea-with-javascript)

```
document.getElementById('myTextArea').value = this.editedConfig;
```

Comment: @TimoCengiz you need to have both the code in `window.onload` and to be setting the `.value` property.

Comment: Same as described, no error now but still no text is updated. empty textarea :(

Comment: @TimoCengiz then, the only thing I can think of is that there is another update to the text area that happens after this. I'm not familiar enough with Vue - perhaps what you have is the wrong setup and you should be doing the update in a different way?

Comment: Going back one step.. What do you mean with ´you need to have both the code´ what is ´code´ in this context? i only put the ´.value´ row in ´window.onload´

Comment: If you only put `document.getElementById('myTextArea').value = this.editedConfig;` in `window.onload`, then you wouldn't have the value of `this.editedConfig`

Comment: Put all the code in window.onload still did not work. @jom's answer did the trick. Thank you for the help