# How to prevent Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) on textarea element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, csrf

I found many answers here and elsewhere on preventing CSRF.

I managed to convert them from jQuery to ES6. Sadly it only works well for `input`, but not for `textarea` elements.

```js
/* Prevent click-jacking with invisible iframes */
if (top.location !== window.location) 
    top.location = window.location;

/* Prevent HTML tags in inputs and textareas */
const sanitizationRegex = /<(|\/|[^>\/bi]|\/[^>bi]|[^\/>][^>]+|\/[^>][^>]+)>/g
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')]
const textareas = [...document.querySelectorAll('textarea')]
const sanitizeInput = function(element) {
    element.value = element.value.replaceAll(sanitizationRegex, '')
}
const sanitizeTextarea = function(element) {
    element.innerText = element.innerText.replaceAll(sanitizationRegex, '')
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replaceAll(sanitizationRegex, '')
};
inputs.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('keyup', () => sanitizeInput(element))
    element.addEventListener('change', () => sanitizeInput(element))
});
textareas.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('keyup', () => sanitizeTextarea(element))
    element.addEventListener('change', () => sanitizeTextarea(element))
})
```

As you can see I tried using `innerText` as well as `innerHTML` for `textarea` but neither worked. I also tried the same thing with `innerContent` but that just resulted in error logs.

Note: Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/S3C_MM/pen/YzZberY), with the first three lines removed.

Comment: CodePen has been fixed to reflect Peter answer on how to do it for textareas. But please read his answer and visit links for further explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Cross Site Request Forgery ([CSRF](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf)) you are trying to prevent, it is Cross Site Scripting ([XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/)).

**CSRF**: Save the form's HTML code on another server and send the `POST` request from somewhere else. CSRF Tokens are the usual solution for this. They are created and validated server-side.

**XSS**: Not preventing or filtering HTML tags can lead to attackers adding script tags with malicious code. JavaScript can help sanitize for innocent users, but countermeasures must be done server-side as well.

You want HTML tags to be filtered out. You are using JavaScript.
JavaScript can be easily edited in-browser with the browser's development tools. An attacker can just add a break point, add `return;` as the first line of your sanitation function before it is called and completely negate your efforts.
You can put *some* sanitation into JavaScript just to offset some computation power to the browser but it seems this is your only strategy.
You must filter HTML tags server-side no matter what.

Now we have that out of the way...
You change the value of textareas with `.value` as well: [How to change the Content of a textarea with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642447/how-to-change-the-content-of-a-textarea-with-javascript).

Comment: Extremely useful answer  @PeterKrebs! I see there's REFLECTED cross site scripting as well. Would you mind editing your answer to take it into consideration? Also would anyone care to suggest a better question title for this answer to appropriately reach more people?

Comment: Reflected cross-site scripting is also already talked about in the linked article about XSS. In general: Just read all of [OWASP](https://owasp.org/)'s articles : )